# Is 1½ hours enough for a transit at São Paulo (GRU) airport?

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, brazil, gru, tam-airlines

I'm flying back from Fortaleza, Brazil to Paris through São Paulo and have 1h 35min transit time in São Paulo airport. I'm wondering if that is enough?

I'm an EU citizen and do not require a visa to enter Brazil. And both flights are served by TAM Airlines, so I'm assuming that luggage will be handled by the company.

Are there any likely options to speed up the security process somehow, if, for example, the first plane arrives late?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bought it on one ticket then yes, it is sufficient time or it would not have been sold to you (alright perhaps I am an optimist!). Your luggage will be through-checked to CDG, if on one ticket.

(If it is on two tickets it should still be possible to arrange for it to be through-checked and to pick up your GRU-CDG boarding pass at FOR. However I would not advise buying your tickets this way.)

You haven't said which airport it is (São Paulo has two), but since you are flying to Paris on TAM I conclude it is Guarulhos (GRU).

The minimum connect time at GRU for domestic to international (D/I) is 1 hour:

```
STANDARD.D/D...D/I...I/D...I/I.
ONLINE   1.00  1.00  1.30  1.00
OFFLINE  1.00  1.00  1.30  1.00
```

(There are some exceptions, but your flights are not in the list.)

There is a terminal change going from terminal 2 to terminal 3. Unfortunately, I think you will have to re-clear security at terminal 3—perhaps someone can confirm this?