# Are T2 and T3 different building at the Sao Paolo GRU Airport

Tags: transit, airports, brazil, sao-paulo

I will be traveling back from Montevideo to Amsterdam with a transit via Sao Paolo Airport.

I have a single ticket (booking)

I found a [previous thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48898/is-1%c2%bd-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-s%c3%a3o-paulo-gru-airport) which state that 1.30 Hours at the Sao Paolo Airport should be enough for transit. I  will be traveling only with hand luggage and no additional bag (and willing to run in order to reach the gate, if need be).

Are T2 and T3 terminals different buildings all-together and how long does one need to reach from one to another?

I arrive in Terminal 2 and need to catch my flight in Terminal 3 and does one need to through security checks again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found the following information:

[Wikipedia Sao Paulo Guarulhos International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo%E2%80%93Guarulhos_International_Airport#Terminals)

> Terminals 2 and 3 are directly linked by a walkway.

Went more deep to find some [TripAdvisor Thread - Transfer fdrom T3 to T2](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g303631-i2161-k9767012-GRU_Transfer_from_T3_to_T2-Sao_Paulo_State_of_Sao_Paulo.html) where I found the following image which shows the above mentioned walkway.

[image: GRU Airport Terminals]

The thread mentions that even during the Rio Olympics the person made from disembarkment area to the T2 terminal in under an hour.

I found some YouTube videos from *Departure Levels* which provides a sneak peak inside the T2 T3 terminals

1. [T2 Domestic to T3 International](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDKqx9_Oxvo)
2. [T3 International Arrival to Immigration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBqxdG_4Ex8&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: T2 from T3, you can go walking.

Comment: are you aware if there are security checks for both the terminals and how much time does is normally take?

Comment: there are security checks in different places in both terminals. I believe you will not spend more than 20 min between both terminals